# DocuSign add recipient with Manage Envelope action

Tags: docusign

So I would like to add a recipient without a role but with Manage Envelope action. This is possible when you add recipients manually but i wanna do it over query string. so far my crl looks like this

```
clrc += 'FirstName~' + somestring + ';LastName~' + somestring  + ';Action~Manage+Envelope;Email~' + somestring  + ';RoutingOrder~1;';
```

So i would like that this user can change envelope but doesn't have to sign it. So basically, wanna accomplish what is explained in this link 
https://www.docusign.com/support/classic/documentation/cdse-user-guide/advanced-sending/agent-envelopes